# Elixir - cannot run mix test in dockerized app

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework, semaphore-ci

I have this semaphore [configuration](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/3a9a10df846963e7c6215ca7cfdba494)

All tests pass except for the last one "Test Elixir". Instead I am getting the following error:

```
** (RuntimeError) cannot configure sandbox with pool DBConnection.Poolboy.
To use the SQL Sandbox, configure your repository pool as:

      pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox

    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql/sandbox.ex:429: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:370: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum.each/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/test.ex:229: Mix.Tasks.Test.run/1
```

Comment: Please post content of your configuration in `config/test.exs`. it seems you forgot to add this line: `  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox`

Comment: @vahidabdi [Here](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/6465913fc09e11e24ef37435bee16a9f). It's already present in the third config. Do I have to put it in the first two as well?

Comment: I think you only need to add it in the first branch

Comment: I'm not familiar with semaphore, but it looks to me like whatever box your tests are actually running in has a `MIX_ENV` that is not 'test'. What's the `MIX_ENV` in your `Dockerfile.test`?

Comment: @vahidabdi is right you need to add the sandbox pool to your configuration in config/test.exs. Here's the docs: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/guides/Testing%20with%20Ecto.md